# Multiple Indexing a class?

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following code:

```py
class C:
    def __getitem__(self,a,b):
        return 1

c = C()
c[2,3]
```

`TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument : b`

My question is how do I feed a 2nd argument when indexing `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to handle this directly in `__getitem__`[(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__); you'd have to have `c[x]` return some kind of sub-object that you could use the second inxed `[y]` on to get the individual item. What you probably want is to have `__getitem__` accept a tuple with such coordinates:

```
def __getitem__(self, tuple):
    y, x = tuple
    return self.matrix[y][x]
```

Then do:

```
c[x, y]
```